# How to union rows on the table mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this values on the table:

```
id|field_id|value_text
1|  1|  msk 
1|  2|  anton
1|  4|  adm@site.com
2|  1|  spb
2|  2|  serg
2|  4|  rr@sk.ru
3|  1|  rng
3|  2|  moya
3|  4|ore@kole.com
```

How can I get this like:

```
id|city|name|email
1|msk|anton|adm@site.com
2|spb|serg|rr@sk.ru
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like you want to `pivot` the table

Try

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN field_id = 1 THEN value_text END) AS city, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN field_id = 2 THEN value_text END) AS name, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN field_id = 4 THEN value_text END) AS email
FROM tbl
GROUP BY id
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2519f/2)